# Insert SQL data into row with same id?

Tags: sql, insert, exists

Is there a SQL command for inserting data into a row where the id = the table id, and if it doesnt exists then insert into a new row?

Something like: 
    ('INSERT INTO USERS IF EXISTS WHERE userID=ID')

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Do an internet search for UPSERT.  Include the brand of RDBMS you are using in your search.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361340/how-to-insert-if-not-exists-in-mysql

Comment: Look into the `MERGE` statement if you're using `ORACLE`

Answer (score 1):

I understood your question like this

```
INSERT INTO table1(value1, value2) 
SELECT value1, value2 FROM table2where table2.userID =  Id
```

Comment: Nope.  That's not what he wants.

Comment: then he has to use sql case statement

Comment: Try doing a Google Search for UPSERT SQL.

Comment: Does upsert works in very database?I mean like db2 or someother databases

Comment: Every database does it a bit differently.  Those that support the SQL 2003 standard and above can use [MERGE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_(SQL)).

Answer (score 1):

You can write something simple like this:

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(t.ID) FROM t WHERE t.ID=@id)=1
    UPDATE
ELSE
    INSERT
```